# JComboBox in JTable not displaying options, only the correct number of blank options

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jcombobox

I'm trying to read the values of a column (which is called parts) from a database table ( called stock_info) into a `JComboBox` which is in a `JTable` (called `tblContents`). My code is below. When running the file, the combo boxes appear in the table, and when clicking on them to select an option they expand with 8 blank options, because there are 8 values in the column in the database table.

Could anyone explain why the options are all blank?

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class Sale extends javax.swing.JFrame {

PreparedStatement pst = null;
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
int count = 0;

public void FillCmbs() {

    String sql = "SELECT * from stockinfo ORDER BY parts";
    int size = 0;

    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            size++;
        }
        String[] items = new String[size];
        while (rs.next()) {
            items[count] = rs.getString("parts");
            count++;
        }
        JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox(items);
        TableColumn tc = tblContents.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        TableCellEditor tce = new DefaultCellEditor(jcb);
        tc.setCellEditor(tce);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

public Sale() {
    initComponents();
    conn = DBConnect.ConnectDB();

}

private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                     
    FillCmbs();
}                                    

public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Sale().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable tblContents;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After the first `while` loop navigates across the `ResultSet` `rs`  the subsequent `while` loop is never entered as there as no more available records and `rs.next()` returns `false`

```
while (rs.next()) {
   items[count] = rs.getString("parts");
   ...
}
```

Rather than determine the size of the `String` array `items` using a separate loop, use an `Vector<String>` to build a collection of Strings. This can then be passed directly to the `JComboBox` constructor *after* a single navigation of the `ResultSet`.

```
Vector<String> data = new Vector<>();
while (rs.next()) {
   data.add(rs.getString("parts"));
}

count = data.size();
JComboBox<String> jcb = new JComboBox<>(data);
```

As a bonus the `count` variable equates to `data.size()`

Comment: +1 but, if you use this approach then use a Vector instead of an ArrayList. When you use an Array in the constructor of a JComboBox a DefaultComboBoxModel will be created which will copy the elements from the Array to a newly created Vector. If you use a Vector as a constructor then the Vector is just used by the model.

Answer (score 0):

No need for an array or ArrayList. Just create the combo box before you start the loop. Then use:

```
comboBox.addItem( rs.getString("parts") );
```